# Is it possible to delete a row in this table?

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

This is a little project I made that displays fake blog posts by their **id** and **title**. Currently, this is how far I've come, however, I need help with how to **delete** a table row (deleting a row should also reflect in the server API). Please can anyone share their thoughts or ideas on how I can make the delete button - on the table - work?

```js
const blog_list = document.getElementById('blog_list')

let limit = 15

async function getBlogs() {
  const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=${limit}`)
  const responseToJSObject = await response.json()
  return responseToJSObject
}

async function showBlogs() {
  const blogs = await getBlogs()
  blogs.forEach(function(blog) {
    blog_list.innerHTML += `
            <tr>
                <td>${blog['id']}</td>
                <td>${blog['title']}</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        `
  })
}

showBlogs()
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Yu Gothic UI';
  background-color: #1c223b;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

div#container {
  background-color: #273349;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(12, 16, 31, 0.4);
  padding: 10px;
}

table {
  color: #e0e0e0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
}

table th,
table td {
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px;
}

table th {
  /*text-transform: capitalize;*/
}

table tbody tr {
  background-color: #1c223b;
}

table tbody tr td button.delete {
  background-color: #242c4c;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #909090;
  font-size: 16px;
  /*padding: 5px 10px;*/
}

table tbody tr td button.delete:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans&display=swap" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  <title>Fetch API Using Async Await with JavaScript From Scratch</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="blog_list">
        <!-- populate table rows here -->
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can't overwrite data from that open free API. Think how it would affect other people if you could. You'll have to write your own server with a CRUD API.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the parent.children property of an element it is a list of elements which are child of the parent

so lets say you want to delete the 1st row of the table

```
let to_remove = blog_list.children[0];
to_remove.remove();
```

hope that answers you question

Comment: Even if it does work I'm not sure it would reflect in the API server

Comment: you have to yourself create a server to pass the modified list so that it can be edited on the database.

Comment: i assumed you had problem in deleting row from front-end

Comment: Please could you assist me to put this in the code so it runs as you have said?